# Is Docker Machine only used when dockerd is running in virtual machines not in actual machines?

Tags: docker

https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#whats-the-difference-between-docker-engine-and-docker-machine says

> Docker Machine is a tool for provisioning and managing
>   your **Dockerized hosts (hosts with Docker Engine on them)**. Typically,
>   you install Docker Machine on your local system.
>
> Docker Machine has its own command line client `docker-machine`  and the
>   Docker Engine client,  `docker`.
>
> You can use Machine to install Docker Engine on one or more **virtual
>   systems**. These virtual systems can be local (as when you use Machine
>   to install and run Docker Engine in VirtualBox on Mac or Windows) or
>   remote (as when you use Machine to provision Dockerized hosts on cloud
>   providers). The Dockerized hosts themselves can be thought of, and are
>   sometimes referred to as, managed “machines”.
>
> [image]

Are "dockerized hosts" always virtual machines, not actual machines?

Is Docker Machine (`docker-machine`) only used when dockerd is running in virtual  machines but not in actual machines?

Thanks.

Comment: `docker-machine` and `docker` are basically a docker client which connects to `dockerd` daemon.

Comment: Is it correct that docker-machine can install dockerd? So how can docker-machine be a client if no dockerd is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-machine` can be used on bare-metal with [the generic driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/). It needs a running system with an SSH server; it will take care of installing Docker on the target if necessary, and configuring the host appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. In bare metal case, If not using `docker-machine`, what can I use to do the same thing as `docker-machine`? What is the benefit of using `docker-machine`?

Comment: If you don’t want to use `docker-machine`, you can replicate what it does manually — log in to the target system, install Docker, start the service, or stop it if you want to replicate `docker-machine restart`, etc. The benefit of using `docker-machine` is that it handles all that for you, with a uniform interface regardless of the type of host you’re using (bare metal, VM, cloud host...).